# How to lookup IQN of iSCSI service from a connected client?

Tags: iscsi

I'm using Alcohol iSCSI Sharing Center to share my virtual drive on network.
My Windows and CentOS client had connected successfully using **iSCSI initiator** and **iscsiadm**.
I used command `iscsiadm -m discovery -t sendtargets -p 192.168.1.100` on CentOS to detected IQN information but the result didn't show the IQN as a regular output.

Here is the output : `192.168.1.100:3260,-1 ubuntu16`
*ubuntu16* is my target name configed by Alcohol.

I expect to have a specific IQN like `iqn.1991-05.com.microsoft` so i can boot from that virtual drive in iPXE(sanhook).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
iscsiadm -m discovery -t st -p #your target server IP address#
```

And paste the output here please.

Comment: Thanks for coming, this project is terminated, i used SolarWind Virtual Network DVD devices instead, it has more features and easy to control than Alcohol.

Comment: Mind sharing your link? It looks like SolarWind has no DVD emulator now :( We need to re-publish old DVDs now, and looking for reliable DVD emulator software. Windows and/or Linux.